# Получить файл из устройства, которое не монтируется как лог.диск. WinAPI

Tags: winapi

К компьютеру подключаем устройство (фотоаппарат, андроид-смартфон...)

В списке устройств (Устройства и принтеры) мы его видим и проводником можно его открыть, просмотреть файлы, скопировать.

Как получить файлы таких устройств программно через WinAPI ? `CreateFile(...)` наверное, но какой путь указывать? Что-то типа `C:\path\file.ext` точно не работает, поскольку устройство не монтируется как логический диск (e:, f:, ...).

Как получить список файлов/каталогов на таком устройстве ?

Comment: Вероятно, придется работать с драйвером или API для конкретного протокола.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, скорее всего есть какой-то стандартный программный интерфейс, типа TWAIN для сканеров и вебок, который драйвера реализуют. При этом к самим драйверам напрямую не нужно обращаться.

Comment: @insolor зависит от типа устройства, я более чем уверен

Comment: Поиски в инете привели к следующему результату: описаные выше устройства относятся к классу WPD (Windows portable device) устройств, и для работы с ними есть свой WPD Automation API [ссылка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463548)


Впрочем, возможность доступа к ним через стандартный (CreateFile()) API остается открытым.